# The Android application does not connect to the server from the background

Tags: android, sockets, server, tcp, connection

After launching the application, it connection to the server. I am using Socket. TCP connection type. As long as the application is active on the screen, everything is fine. But if the application is moved to the background and the screen turns off, and after a while the connection with the server is lost, then it is impossible to create a connection again. The socket throws an exception:

**"Unable to resolve host "m15.cloudmqtt.com": No address associated with hostname"**.

Where "m15.cloudmqtt.com" is the server name.
But if you take the phone out of the background and open the application, then the connection occurs immediately.
The creation of a socket is implemented using AsyncTask, which is launched from the Service.
Is it possible to solve this problem? I have been looking for various solutions for several days.

Comment: This is fairly normal for some device manufacturers, such as Samsung. See https://dontkillmyapp.com/ for more.

Comment: Thank you. I have seen that. But I need to programmatically solve this problem in my application.

Comment: Try with the ip of the server instead.

Comment: How can I get it? This is a cloud server. Can his IP change?